# Failed to import algoliasearch to my lib folder

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, instantsearch

I want to import algolia python lib to my python 3 app engine project.

So I did

```
pip install algoliasearch -t lib
```

And in my lib folder I created `__init__.py`

Then In my project I import using

```
from lib.algoliasearch.search_client import SearchClient
```

So far so good. But in algolia library, for instance

```
lib\algoliasearch\search_client.py
```

There is also import statements as below:

```
from algoliasearch.helpers import endpoint, is_async_available
```

this works when I installed globally otherwise for installed in lib folder, it does not work when I deploy app engine.

As a solution I could update those files

```
from lib.algoliasearch.helpers import endpoint, is_async_available
```

which is a terrible solution.

On the other hand, if I apply:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './lib')
```

this time, it is broken at several part i.e.

```
libcrypto_path = find_library(b'crypto' if sys.version_info < (3,) else 'crypto')
if not libcrypto_path:
    raise LibraryNotFoundError('The library libcrypto could not be found')
```

at

```
lib\asn1crypto\_perf\_big_num_ctypes.py
```

How can I properly import this algoliasearch lib?

---

Note: I could guess, Algolia team should update their packages by giving relative paths such as:

instead of

```
from algoliasearch.helpers import endpoint, is_async_available
```

this:

```
from helpers import endpoint, is_async_available
```

Comment: Did you create the app_config.py file as specified here? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

Comment: That’s for python 2.7. I am working with python 3.7

Comment: Can you show the actual import error(s) (ideally with the full traceback)?

Comment: @DanCornilescu There is no stack trace but the error says `-  __exception_info {'exception': ModuleNotFoundError(...asearch'"), 'exception_type': <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, 'message': "No module named 'al...iasearch'"} dict
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I haven't worked clearly, I installed everything to my lib folder in my application.
In fact, only algolia package is enough to install to lib else is in global as long as it does not in app engine environment.

What I do is as solution

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))
```

attention it is not insert to first place, not to do this:

```
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))
```

otherwise, it overrides global package i.e.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\my_project\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from algoliasearch.responses import Response
  File "C:\my_project\lib\algoliasearch\responses.py", line 3, in <module>
    from typing import List, Union, Optional
  File "C:\my_project\lib\typing.py", line 1356, in <module>
    class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
  File "C:\my_project\lib\typing.py", line 1004, in __new__
    self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
```

but the issue reveals is, as I work python app engine project in visual studio 2017,
weirdly visual studio complains in some middle of the importing packages.

As workaround to this, install algolia globally as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you can't just include the [`algoliasearch`](https://pypi.org/project/algoliasearch/) package as a dependency instead of vendoring it in like that?

E.g., in `requirements.txt`:

```
algoliasearch==2.0.0
```

(or whichever version you need)

Comment: Indeed your suggestion works +1, see my answer why this got so complicated